# Component inside alert in react native

Tags: react-native, alert

hello guys i need to put a component(switch) inside an alert,

```
export const secretAlert = (environment: object) => {
  Alert.alert(
    'Alert Title',
    'My Alert Msg',
    [
      {
        text: `Environment: ${Config.ENV}`,
      },
      {
        text: 'Cancel',
        onPress: () => console.log('Cancel Pressed'),
        style: 'cancel',
      },
      { text: 'OK', onPress: () => console.log('OK Pressed') },
    ],
    { cancelable: false },
  );
    return (
          <Text>test</Text>,
    )
}
```

second attempts

```
export const secretAlert = (environment: object) => {
  Alert.alert(
    'Alert Title',
    'My Alert Msg',
    [
      {
        text: `Environment: ${Config.ENV}`,
      },
      {
        text: 'Cancel',
        onPress: () => console.log('Cancel Pressed'),
        style: 'cancel',
        switch: <ComponentHere>. 
      },
      { text: 'OK', onPress: () => console.log('OK Pressed') },
    ],
    { cancelable: false },
  );
}
```

The code above is wrong, it's just to let you know what i've to do. 
There is a way to made it with the default component alert or should i use some library/custom component ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not possible with default react-native `Alert`. You can use this [library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-dialog) and use `Dialog.Switch` or I recommend that you use a [modal](https://reactnative.dev/docs/modal) to highly customize your alert.

Comment: thanks for your answert :) i'm using a custom modal